# How to extract text between quotes containing a specific word?

Tags: php, regex, json

The text between the quotes I am trying to extract, also has quotes within the text, like this: "data":"value"

The specific word is "data".  The "value" will always be different.  Once extracted it should be "data":"value" with the quotes.

So far...

```
<?
$dat = "file.dat";
$text = file_get_contents($dat);
$res = preg_match_all ('/"([^"]*)"/', $text, $matches);
if ($res) {
    foreach (array_unique ($matches[0]) as $data) {
    echo "$data";
}
}
    else {
    echo "No Data Found.";
}
```

My code just extracts any and all words between double quotes.  How do I accomplish what I am trying to do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like a JSON data why don't you try to properly read the JSON object instead? `$res = json_decode($text, true); print_r($res)`

Comment: Or possibly CSV. Before you venture into perfecting the tool you picked, take a step back and explain the actual task you want to accomplish. [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: It is for a webhook for Mandrill.  I am just tying to get the email addresses from it.  Sometimes it throws in a random email address not in my subscriber list.  The email addresses that are in my list use the format stated above.

Comment: https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/webhooks.html indicates JSON. And PHP already provides a parser for that.

Comment: @Brian by the looks of it, that mess of information is json, try Prix suggestion above on the result.

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments noticed. The format you are trying to parse is JSON and PHP comes with a easy to use function to parse JSON. You could try this:

```
<?
$dat = "file.dat";
$text = file_get_contents($dat);
$res = json_decode($text, true);
if ($res) {
    foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
        echo "$key => $value";
    }
}
    else {
    echo "No Data Found.";
}
```

Untested, but should get the job done.

Comment: Just echoes "No Data Found"

Comment: You can analyse what is saved in $res by adding the line var_dump($rest); before the if statement. It should tell you its an array and its content. If it doesn't leave a comment.